# Create a sheet that unify other sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, union, google-workspace

I have a file with several sheets, they're all the same but contain data from different sources.

I would like to create a new sheet that updates automatically and give me the total of all the other sheets combined.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I understand that your sheets are `all the same` and the information on them comes from `different sources`, but can you share some data as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It doesn't have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. Like a dummy sheet so we can visualize and replicate what you have. You may include your desired output in it as well.

Comment: Hi Saddles, thanks for your answer.

This is a sample of the file 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rql-mAZVcPJQhTqKtBexs8QVRBw94V0Cwrfn4Nn_bLg/edit#gid=887317828

You understood correctly, all the sheets are exactly the same and data comes from different sources. Every tab has a left part where I input the data and a right part where results are shown. 
In the TOTAL tab, the left part could be removed since I only need the results on the right part.

Thanks for help

Comment: I was able to review the spreadsheet that you provided. I see that you already have a computation of the data from the other sheets on the right of the `TOTAL` tab, and with the information that you'd like to compute, it's best to use the method that you're already using, which is to utilize a helper column on the left of the sheet and just have it hidden if you don't want to see it.

Comment: Yes, In the meanwhile, with help, I was able to come out with such soluition that seems to work pretty well with what I needed. Thanks for your time!